# How to append a character between two characters in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a list as below;

```
paramone=somerandomvalue; paramtwo=somerandomvalue; paramthree=somerandomvalue;
```

I want to append a * (asterisk) at the end of every 'somerandomvalue' but before ; (semicolon) like below -

```
paramone=somerandomvalue*; paramtwo=somerandomvalue*; paramthree=somevrandomalue*;
```

**NOTE** - It should only append the strings that have = and ; . There are other strings having ; at the end but doesn't have a =.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your input had the following content

```
$ cat input_file
paramone=somerandomvalue; paramtwo=somerandomvalue; paramthree~somerandomvalue;paramone=somerandomvalue; paramtwo=somerandomvalue; paramthree##somerandomvalue;
```

Using `sed`

```
$ sed s'/\(=[^;]*\)/\1*/g' input_file
paramone=somerandomvalue*; paramtwo=somerandomvalue*; paramthree~somerandomvalue;paramone=somerandomvalue*; paramtwo=somerandomvalue*; paramthree##somerandomvalue;
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It is actually good but would end up appending values that doesn't have ; It checks for = . If a ; exists it would append right before it. This solved 90% of the problem. I would use regex for removing the * at the end of certain values. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd leverage `sed` to do this:

```
sed 's/;/*;/g' test.txt
```

Something like that. Assuming every value has that `;` at the end of it.

Comment: It would append when it sees a ; and it won't check for a =. the string is between = and ; There are other values in the list which has ; but there isn't a = so it would end up appending those values too. I don't want that.

Comment: Cool, no worries, i didn't have that information. But at least what i gave you is something to start with. If you look at the other answers they are more verbose and probably can catch some of the issues you've now mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work -
`sed s'/=\(.*\)?;/\1*/g' <input_file_name>`